How to conditionally render the default Admin navigation link in Filament PHP?
With Filament PHP, I have a 'Dashboard' navigation link that loads '/admin' URL in the browser. I want to render the navigation link conditionally. How can I do this?

If using filament to conditionally render the link you can add ->visible('your condition here') or if using laravel a simple if statement would do the job

Navigation Items (ex. Dashboards) registeration can be controlled with the following variable.
protected static bool $shouldRegisterNavigation

Furthermore you could use the function to calculate your condition.
public static function shouldRegisterNavigation(): bool
{
    return \Auth::id() == 1;
}

If what you are looking for is permitting the dashboard for specific users. You can use a package like filament-shield which laverages policies to control access per user role.
